# build release for jar files in windows

Tags: build, batch-file, jar

I an new to build release, Can you please help me how to write ".bat" file to execute jar files in windows.

Please give me some inputs on how to proceed with simple example.

Comment: you want to build release (build jar file) or execute jar file?

Comment: I want build release.. I have jar files. using .bat I should be able to run all jar files.

Comment: I didn't get you. what do you mean by building release? my understanding is you have a lot of source codes (.java file) and you compile them and build into a jar. define "build" in your context pls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write a simple text file (let's say run.txt) containing the text

```
java -jar jarfile.jar
```

then rename it to run.bat.

You could also use tools like javaexe to create executable files to run the jar by double clicking.
http://devwizard.free.fr/html/en/JavaExe.html

Comment: To build java code to jar files you should use javac with the correct options, but you should edit your question.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to execute "a.jar", then the command is

```
java -jar a.jar
```

This statement can be put in a bat file as follows
 - Open notepad.exe
 - Write the above statement in the file
 - Save as f.bat (f can be any file name that you choose)